# i can't run the app on android atudio

Tags: android-studio

Some help this error still appear even if I changed the `minsdkversion` and the `compile`

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':hoppingBird:processDebugManifest'.

Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0] C:\Users\mohssin\Downloads\Documents\HoppingBird\hoppingBird\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads\9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage
```

Comment: Improve your question title. Put some description of the error, to make easier to another user to find it.

Comment: See my answer. I hope it helps you. @Mohssinf91

Answer (score 0):

There are two places:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" ...
```

and **build.gradle:**

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to **Google's Documentation**

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

```
   1. A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
   2. The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.
```

So just change your `minimum sdk version` into `9` ( API Level: 9 -> Android 2.3 )

In **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

In **build.gradle**:

```
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 9

}
```

and **rebuild** your project. 
Here's the link to setting up [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)